# Use lazysizes to detect when a DOM node enters the viewport

Tags: javascript, dom, polyfills, intersection-observer

I want a callback to be called when a specific DOM node enters the viewport.

Additionally I have the following situation:

- [`aFarkas/lazysizes`](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) is used on the page.
- [`Intersection Observer API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Browser_compatibility) is not implemented in some of the Browsers that need to be supported.

I don't want to add a [`Intersection Observer Polyfill`](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill) as `aFarkas/lazysizes` comes bundled with the same functionality.

Hence my question: Is it possible to use `aFarkas/lazysizes` to detect when a DOM node enters the viewport?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `data-expand` attribute to tell `aFarkas/lazysizes` when to trigger the `lazybeforeunveil` event as follows:

```html
<div class="lazyload" data-expand="-20">
  This will trigger a lazybeforeunveil event
  when entering the viewport.
</div>
```

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'lazybeforeunveil', callback, false
);
```

See the documentation for the `data-expand` attribute: [aFarkas/lazysizes#data-expand-attribute](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#data-expand-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think its possible.

Looks like aFarkas/lazysizes only uses the intersection observer if available: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/master/src/lazysizes-intersection.js#L11

Otherwise they throttle an internal function called `checkElements` that is triggered on every scroll. https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/master/src/lazysizes-core.js#L332

Does not look like they expose this function: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/master/src/lazysizes-core.js#L676

They don't fully polyfill it, they just implement the *make sure something is visible part* themselves. So could you depending on what you are doing.

``

Comment: `lazysizes-intersection.js` is a version of lazysizes that relies on the intersection observer. See this comment: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/issues/263#issuecomment-261249555